# My Google account was deleted, how do I sign into phone with that account

Tags: google

I am giving away one of my older android phones that was signed into one of my older Google accounts. The thing is that that account was deleted and I can't sign back into the phone, does anyone know how to fix this/bypass this?

Answer (score 0):

Google says you may still be able to reopen the account:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6236295?hl=en